# MS Access parameter query

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I have VBA code to open a parameter query, export the query to Excel and then close the query. My problem is that when I input a parameter I get the first export window and then I have to put the parameter in again to finish the export. I would like to be asked only once for the parameter. Here is the code:

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Chapter Roster and Year Dues Paid", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdExportExcel
DoCmd.Close acQuery, "Chapter Roster and Year Dues Paid", acSaveNo

cmdViewChapterRosters_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

cmdViewChapterRosters_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume cmdViewChapterRosters_Click_Exit
```

I have created the response parameter in the query with this code: *[Which Chapter?]* is in the *[Chapter Number]* field of the query.

Answer (score 1):

Consider having user enter needed query value on form and then reference this control directly in query. This will then eliminate any pop-ups which usually should not be part of user interface but warning that a missing value, unknown column, etc. is needed to process query.

Also, consider dedicated export methods such as `TransferSpreadsheet` and `OutputTo` that do not require opening stored query to screen:

**SQL** *(adjust current query)*

```sql
SELECT * FROM TableData WHERE [Chapter Number] = Forms!frmName!TextFieldName
```

**VBA**  *(both will prompt for file name unless file name path arg is declared)*

```vb
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "QueryName"
'DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "QueryName", acFormatXLSX
```

Answer (score -2):

My favorite code line is: DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "Query/Table Name", acFormatXLSX, "FileName.xlsx", 0

Hope this help. Regards.